# Having a difficult time figuring out how to find running time in Theta notation of a nested for loop

Tags: algorithm, runtime

I have a triple nested for loop, that needs to be expressed in Theta for running time (complexity).

I ended up with Theta(n^3) but not 100% sure if my reasoning is correct.

```
func(n)
x = 0 
for i = 1 to n do
   for  j = 1 to i do
      for k = j to i + j do
          x <- x + 1
return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this step by step from the inner to the outermost loop:

```
func(n)
x = 0 
for i = 1 to n do
   for  j = 1 to i do
      for k = j to i + j do
          x <- x + 1
return x
```

Start from the inner-most statement. `x <- x + 1` is a single instruction, so

```
func(n)
x = 0 
for i = 1 to n do
   for  j = 1 to i do
      for k = j to i + j do
          Theta(1)
return x
```

The next loop runs `(i + j) - j + 1 = i + 1` times:

```
func(n)
x = 0 
for i = 1 to n do
   for  j = 1 to i do
      Theta(i)
return x
```

Proceeding in this way, we get:

```
func(n)
    x = 0 
    for i = 1 to n do
       Theta(i^2)
    return x
```

and finally, using the fact that the sum of squares from 1 to `n` is `n(n + 1)(2n + 1)/6 = n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6 = Theta(n^3)`:

```
func(n)
    x = 0 
    Theta(n^3)
    return x
```

Since all remaining statements run in constant time, the overall complexity is `Theta(n^3)`.

Comment: This code has a complexity of O(n^3) as well, what about Omega? @Paul

Comment: @ManojBanik If a code is both `O(n^3)` and `Omega(n^3)` it's automatically `Theta(n^3)` and vice versa. That's the standard definition of Theta-timecomplexity. Basically the above proof just unifies the proofs for lower and upper bound into one single line of argument for convenience.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see. Assuming that n is very large (otherwise complexity would not be an issue). Your outer loop has n steps. The intermediary loop has roughly n / 2 steps.

To understand the inner loop, let's think about its boundaries. The end is i + j and the start is j, so the number of elements is i + j - j + 1, which is i + 1. This can be very very small if i = 1 or very very large, if i is practically infinite (n).

Infinity has a property that

Infinity / 2 = Infinity

So, even n / 2 would be not finite if we assume infinity as the value of n. So, your result is correct, we have Theta(n^3), of course, we do not really care about adding some constant value or multiplying n with a finite strictly positive number.

Comment: That proof doesn't work. Try with `Theta(log(n))` or `Theta(2^n)`. All you can proof that way is that the algorithm is `o(1)`.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what you want to say.

Comment: These two statements "So, even n / 2 would be not finite if we assume infinity as the value of n. So, your result is correct, we have Theta(n^3), of course, ..." don't correlate in any way. If you want to work with infinity you'll have to actually compare the functions like this: `lim n->inf n^3/g(n)`, where `g(n)` describes the number of steps the algorithm takes depending on `n` and proof it's convergence to a value different from 0.

Comment: @Paul we divide n with constants. Infinity / 2 = Infinity. And a proof doesn't "work", since it's not a machine or a product of engineering. A proof is a theoretical product.

Comment: Call it what you want. Either way this is no theoretical product of any sort, simply because it completely ignores basic logical rules. From a mathematical POV it's already wrong to say "Infinity / 2", since infinity isn't defined as a member of any algebraic object. But even ignoring that, your proof has quite a few weaknesses: you can't conclude much from the fact that `lim n->inf n = inf`, "has roughly n/2 steps" is nothing you can base an actual proof on, you can't combine these two facts to derive anything about the two inner loops, etc

Comment: "has roughly n / 2 steps" means that on average there are n / 2 steps, because we are going from 1 to i. At first there is a single such step, at the end all n elements are looped through. Between the too there is a steady growth. I think this should be understandable for someone who wants to understand.